# Page says 'waiting' only for some users, works for others?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, dns, vhosts

I am using name based hosting with 2 ips on my EC2 instance. I used Route53 for my DNS.

I can load the sites fine, an I tested from 20 locations (friends and VPN), all fine. Then I go to one house and one office that are having the problem (one on Cox and one on Century Link) and the page wont load.

When I visit the page it says 'waiting'. If I change it to use Google DNS 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 it loads fine.

Tail -f access log show initial connection from that IP, status 200.
No other hits from user/no images.css etc pulled from server, just initial line.
When I try to call a specific image, Chrome logs show 200 success, but ony 1k.
If I put up test.html with plain text in it, ie Hello, it loads fine.

Could this be something with my EC2 / Name Based setup? Since it loads for 95% off all people, I'm stuck.

CentoS.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

After thorough testing with an AWS rep, no reason could be found. Intermittent connections, and could not FTP or SSH in from locations URL did not come up.

Fix: Stop and Start instance. This will launch instance on new hardware without issues. Worked great.

Make sure you have an AMI or at least a Snapshot.